# asp.net core web api extend authenticate type with windows auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

having asp.net core API which already supports API key authentication and authorization, is there a way how to add windows authentication?

in order to authenticate the request with windows auth, I would need username and password. Where and how can I get it?

current code which supports API key authentication:

**startup.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme;
}).AddApiKeySupport(options => { });
```

**AuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs**

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddApiKeySupport(this AuthenticationBuilder authenticationBuilder, Action<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions> options)
{
    return authenticationBuilder.AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme, options);
}
```

where `ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler` contains custom authentication and authorization logic using ApiKey.

Comment: `in order to authenticate the request with windows auth, I would need username and password.` quite the opposite - there's no need for username/password. Windows Authentication means that the client and server communicate to send the *client account's* identity to the server. For that to work, client and server must be on the same or trusted domains. The client should use a domain account. This is no different than accessing eg a file share on a server, or connecting to a SQL Server database using Windows Authentication

Comment: Check [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth) in the docs

Comment: considering that users using windows authentication wont have api key in their requests, how can I fallback to another type of authentication in case that first one fails?

Comment: You could consider using claims-based authorization via policies, after setting windows authentication in your application, you could add custom claim to ClaimsPrincipal ,check user's identity and confirm which permission current user, and also try to check whether the Request context contains the API Key, then, add the custom claim, after that, based on the claim to authenticate the user. You can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524466/). Besides, when you configure Windows authentication, remember to enable anonymousAuthentication.