# Custom principal displays Forbidden on Authorize Filter attribute ASP.Net Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

The application is an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app and uses Windows authentication. Currently I have a `ClaimsTransformation` like this:

```
public class ClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

    public ClaimsTransformation(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = accessor;
        _authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
       if (principal != null && principal.Identity != null && !principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return principal;

        var clonedPrincipal = principal.Clone();
        var clonedClaims = clonedPrincipal.Claims.ToList();
        var clonedIdentity = clonedPrincipal.Identity;

        var customPrincipal = _authenticationService.WindowsAuthenticate(clonedIdentity);
        var customIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)customPrincipal.Identity;

        foreach (var claim in clonedClaims)
        {
            customIdentity.AddClaim(claim);
        }

        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User = customPrincipal;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

        return await Task.FromResult(customPrincipal);
    }
}
```

However, when it reaches the controller which has a `[Authorize]` attribute, it displays a http 403 error. Kindly suggest. Thanks

Comment: Pls use the exist user account in your domain to login. To make sure this issue not related to wrong account. And you also can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53533020/7687666) to check your `ClaimsTransformation ` class.

Comment: Thanks for this. Got it working via policy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will summarize it as answer below. Hope it can help more forum users who will face the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Create the `ClaimsTransformation` in our application.**

**2. Register it in startup file.**

```
    Startup.cs(.net Core <=5.0) :

    services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();

    Program.cs(.net Core >=6.0) :

    builder.Services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
```

**3. Set the policy.**

```
   //.net core <= 5.0
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
       options.AddPolicy("Readonly", policy =>
                      policy.RequireClaim("permission", "readOnly"));

       options.AddPolicy("Write", policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim("permission", "write"));
   });

   //.net core >= 6.0
   builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
       options.AddPolicy("Readonly", policy =>
                      policy.RequireClaim("permission", "readOnly"));

       options.AddPolicy("Write", policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim("permission", "write"));
   });
```

**4. Use it in the controller.**

```
   [Authorize(Policy = "Write")]
   public IActionResult Contact()
   {
       ...
   }
```